# How to install dompdf in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, dompdf

I had install laravel-dompdf follow this : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

But after i use that pdf, laravel-dompdf many shortcomings. It can not display: flex, float etc

And after I search in google, I find this : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Are these two links the same?

Are dompdf and laravel-dompdf the same?

I see the second link (dompdf), it looks like it's a lot of updates.

How do I install dompdf besides laravel-dompdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one, https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf is the original core library, a pure PHP library.

The first one, https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf is a [wrapper library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) for using DomPDF in Laravel.

You need the second one, which will automatically include and use the first one, upon proper installation.

The DomPDF core library has more recent commits, but [the newest released version (at the time of this posting) is 0.8](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases), which is the same which is used [in the wrapper library for Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/commit/22ee9cb8e0ac0d5f11633d1194280ab40b2bba1f) currently. The more recent commits in the [DomPDF core](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) GitHub repository have not yet been made to a new release, but it seems from the [commit history](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/commits/master) the features you mentioned have also not been implemented in those newer commits yet.

So the Laravel wrapper DomPDF is using the most current released version of the vanilla PHP library DomPDF, which is fine.

The [DomPDF core Readme](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#features) says:

> Handles **most** CSS 2.1 and **a few** CSS3 properties, including @import, @media & @page rules

(**bold** emphasis mine)

So not even CSS 2.1 is completely supported yet. There are missing features. I assume flex and float are among those as of yet unsupported features.

You would have to wait for them to be included in the DomPDF core library in some future version, and then, for the Laravel Wrapper to be updated as well to that new version.

Comment: So, the solution to my problem is : I must install dompdf (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) in my laravel. Right?

Comment: No, https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf is the correct library for Laravel. It already includes the DomPDF core library as maintained on https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf (in version 0.8 currently).

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf already includes the newest released version of https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

As you say, it has *"many shortcomings. It can not display: flex, float etc"*.
But there is no way to change that. These features are just not yet implemented in DomPDF. So you'll have to make do without them.

Comment: So you already have the correct version.

There is nothing you can do at this point about the shortcomings. Flex etc. is not implemented yet in DomPDF. Nothing you can do.

Comment: I read here : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/971 & https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1409. It had updated

Comment: If you read carefully about the first one (flex support), you would see that this is a *still open issue*. Flex support has not been implemented yet.

About the other (float support): That seems to have been fixed. But that happened already long ago, so should work fine already with v0.8.

How old is your installation of dompdf? You should use the newest version from https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Maybe a reinstall will help to make the float work. Apart from that I don't have any idea. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for you help